# Using the new httpclient-4.0.1 jar with a project using commons-httpclient

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Could I safely include the httpclient-4.0.1 jar that replaced the commons-httpclient jar that is now end of life or should I worry about having some conflict between both?

Some of my code is using commons-httpclient, should I be worried that having both would bring some problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not. HttpClient 3.x and Httpclient 4.x share no common dependencies beyond Commons Logging and Commons Codec and should be able to co-exist in the same class loader just fine.

Comment: They also use different Java package names, which is critical.